# Meteor: I can't get the onError callback to fire when throwing error from subscription

Tags: meteor

Ok this is the server code where I publish my data if the current user have access to see it

```js
# server publish
Meteor.publish 'clients', (locationId) ->
if SecurityContext.canAccessLocation @userId, locationId
    @ready()
    @error new Meteor.Error('unauthorized', 'You do not have access to this location')
    return

ClientManagement.Collections.Clients.find({ locationId: locationId }, { sort: firstName: 1 })
```

This is a section of my iron-router's controller where I wait for my data to come back but my callbacks for onReady or onError are never called

```js
# iron route controller
waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'clients', Session.get 'selectedLocationId',
        onReady: ->
            debugger
        onError: (error) ->
            debugger
            AppHelper.logger.error error.reason
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions? I also tried something similar outside of iron-router just to double check it was not related to the router.

I did this on the client side:

```js
Meteor.startup () ->

  Tracker.autorun ->
      Meteor.subscribe 'clients', Session.get 'selectedLocationId',
          onReady: ->
              debugger
          onError: (error) ->
              debugger
              AppHelper.logger.error error.reason
```

Again nothing my callbacks are never called ... any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a coffeescript mistake. The transpiler doesn't know if you mean to include the callback object as an argument to `subscribe` or to `get`. It chooses the latter, but you want the former. Try something like this instead:

```coffee
Meteor.subscribe 'clients', Session.get('selectedLocationId'),
  onReady: ->
    console.log 'ready!'
  onError: ->
    console.log 'error!'
```